# Цепочка последовательных форм Flask

Tags: python, http, flask

Необходимо реализовать функционал последовательного показа форм:

1) Пользователь переходит по ссылке
2) Видит форму, заполняет поля и отправляет
3) Форма проверяется
    3.1) если ошибки пользователю показываемся та же страница, но с ошибками с форме
    3.2) если данные в форме верные пользователь попадает на следующую форму и так далее с пункта 2

Никак не разберусь с пунктом 3.2, как передать данные из 1 формы во вторую если они находятся на разных url, не используя открытую передачу в самом url вида /second_form/{{json_data}}

Comment: Рассмотри возможно реализовать проверку данных с помощью js на странице, а потом просто отправляешь все данные разом

Comment: Я думал над этим вариантом, но не хочется внедрять что-то сверх имеющегося